# which event fires when a listbox finished databinding?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

The ASP.NET GridView (and other controls) has the very handy [DataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound.aspx) event, which fires after the GridView finishes databinding. Is there an equivalent event for the Silverlight ListBox (WP7.1)?

My ListBox changes constantly based on user input and I would like to scroll the listbox to a certain item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such event.

But you could use a more generic change listener like `ItemsChanged`:

```
    listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += new ItemsChangedEventHandler(ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged);
```

This will also react on normal list changes but you can easily filter these.

Answer (score 0):

The ListBox has a SelectedItem property. Just set it to one of the items, or set the SelectedValue and that will automatically scroll it to make visible.
Here is the MSDN reference of that property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem.aspx

Comment: the question was not on how to scroll the listbox, but if there is a DataBound event